# can i use mem_fun like this?

Tags: c++, windows, algorithm, stl, c++11

I want to set the function pointer at runtime. But i'm stuck here. When i use global function or static class member function, everything is ok. but, when the function is ordinary class member functions. i always got compiler errors.
Here is the code:

```
class A   
{
    int val;
public:
    A() { val = 0; }
    A(int j) { val = j; }

    int aFun(int k) {val -= k; return val; }
};

typedef int (* func)(int );
class B
{
    func m_addr;
public:
    B(func param)
        : m_addr(param)
    {

    }
    void execute()
    {
        cout << m_addr(9) << endl;
    }
};
```

I'm trying to use them like this:

> /* error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static
>   member functions error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function
>   taking 1 arguments class does not define an 'operator()' or a user
>   defined conversion operator to a  pointer-to-function or
>   reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments
>   */

```
A a;
B b(A::aFun); 
b.execute();
```

after googled a lot, i found that `std::mem_fun` may be helpful. but i don't know how to use it. anyone can help me?

**PS: i'm using Visual C++ 2010**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class member functions have an extra parameter passed to it the by the compiler called `this`, so the compiler sees `aFun` as begin declared and written as

```
int A::aFun(A* this, int k)
{
    this->val -= k;
    return this->val;
}
```

Static/global functions don't have this parameter and so compilation succeeds.

In order to use `A::aFun` you'll need an instance of class `A` somewhere.

Comment: then, what's your solution to my post? how about std::mem_fun?

Answer (score 0):

modified  as following:

```
static int val;

class A   
{

public:
    A() { val = 0; }
    A(int j) { val = j; }

  static  int aFun(int k) {val -= k; return val; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what are you trying to do but I saw an error, maybe helps you.

That's a pointer to a function, isn't?

```
 typedef int (* func)(int );
```

But you don't have a function, you have a method of a class. (a member function)
So the typedef shoud be probability:

```
typedef int (A::*func)(int );
```

I hope helps you a bit, you can google for pointers to member functions and you will find some examples.

Good luck!

Comment: Note: if you try exactly my code won't work because A::aFun haven't been instanced in B.

Comment: Note2: Now, B b(A::aFun); might be B b(&A::aFun);